# why is my code not returning anything ? Scala fs2

Tags: scala, queue, fs2

The program permits pushing Mapping Ints to Double and identifying the exit time from the queue.
The program is not showing any error but It is not printing anything.
What am I missing ?

```
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp, Timer}
import fs2._
import fs2.concurrent.Queue

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Random
class Tst(q1: Queue[IO, (Double, IO[Long])])(implicit timer: Timer[IO]) {

  val streamData = Stream.emit(1)
  val scheduledStream = Stream.fixedDelay[IO](10.seconds) >> streamData

  def storeInQueue: Stream[IO, Unit] = {
    scheduledStream
      .map { n =>
        val entryTime =
          timer.clock.realTime(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        (n.toDouble, entryTime)
      }
      .through(q1.enqueue)
      .evalTap(n => IO.delay(println(s"Pushing $n to Queue")))

    q1.dequeue
      .evalTap(_ => timer.sleep(Random.between(10, 30).seconds))
      .map { n =>
        val exitTime =
          timer.clock.realTime(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        (n._1, exitTime)
      }
      .evalMap(n => IO.delay(println(s"Pulling from queue $n")))
  }
}

object Five2 extends IOApp {

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val program = for {
      q <- Queue.bounded[IO, (Double, IO[Long])](1)
      b = new Tst(q)
      _ <- b.storeInQueue.compile.drain

    } yield ()
    program.as(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```

Comment: Previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62476044/how-can-i-reuse-a-queue-in-another-computation-fs2-stream-scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IO is evaluated lazily - for something to get executed it has to be a part of expression that created the final IO value.

Here:

```
  def storeInQueue: Stream[IO, Unit] = {
    scheduledStream ... // no side effects are run when we create this!

    q1.dequeue ... // not using scheduledStream
  }
```

value `scheduledStream` is not used at all, so it isn't "a part" of value returned from `storeInQueue` so when `IOApp` turns IO value into computations, the recipe for your program doesn't contain the part where messages are pushed to queue, so the queue is always empty.

The part which subscribes to queue works, but since nothing ever lands on queue it keeps on waiting for items that will never arrive.

You would have to start both streams by "making them part of one IO value", e.g. like this:

```
class Tst(q1: Queue[IO, (Double, IO[Long])])(implicit timer: Timer[IO]) {

  val streamData = Stream.emit(1)
  val scheduledStream = Stream.fixedDelay[IO](10.seconds) >> streamData

  def storeInQueue =
    scheduledStream
      .map { n =>
        val entryTime =
          timer.clock.realTime(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        (n.toDouble, entryTime)
      }
      .through(q1.enqueue)
      .evalTap(n => IO.delay(println(s"Pushing $n to Queue")))

  def takeFromQueue =
    q1.dequeue
      .evalTap(_ => timer.sleep(Random.between(10, 30).seconds))
      .map { n =>
        val exitTime =
          timer.clock.realTime(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        (n._1, exitTime)
      }
      .evalMap(n => IO.delay(println(s"Pulling from queue $n")))
  }
}

object Five2 extends IOApp {

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val program = for {
      q <- Queue.bounded[IO, (Double, IO[Long])](1)
      b = new Tst(q)
      pushFiber <- b.storeInQueue.compile.drain.start // run as fiber
      pullFiber <- b.takeFromQueue.compile.drain.start // run as fiber
    } yield ()
    program.as(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```

Comment: but what If the stream should be used again by another queue after leaving the queue you have just created ?

Comment: You can reuse queue, because they are mutable shared resources wrapped in pure operations, but if you reuse stream from queue, it means that you are running the same computations against the queue that created them twice.

Comment: If I did understand I should return a Queue[IO, Int ] ,and not Stream[IO, Int] , from computation 1 in order to use it un the next computation

Comment: If you want to reuse queue, then reuse queue.

Comment: I'm going to open a new question because I have tried to reuse it and failed